# Proving if a given set of vectors is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is: Is the given set of vectors a vector space? All vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ such that $v_1 + v_2 + v_3 = 1$.

My answer:

This would form the plane $v_1 = 1-v_2-v_3$.

Let's try to see if it is closed under addition:

Consider the following vectors:

$u = [u_1 u_2 u_3]^T$
$v = [v_1 v_2 v_3]^T$

$(u_1+v_1)=1-(u_2+v_2)-(u_3+v_3)$

replacing $u_1 = 1-u_2-u_3$ and $v_1 = 1-v_2-v_3$ in the left side of the equation we get:

$(1-u_2-u_3)+(1-v_2-v_3) = 2-(u_2+v_2)-(u_3+v_3)$

which is different from what we would expect if it was a vector space: $1−(u_2+v_2)−(u_3+v_3)$.

We can see the same with an example:

$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    -1
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}
    -6 \\
    2 \\
    5
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    -5 \\
    3 \\
    4
\end{bmatrix}$

recall that $v_1 = 1-v_2-v_3$, which is not satisfied by the addition property for $(u_1+v_1) = 1-(u_2+v_2)-(u_3+v_3)$:

$-5 \neq 1-3-4$

Is the reasoning all correct and complete? In reality, in a kind of problem like this, the fact that we are summing a constant would always result in the set of vectors not creating a vector space, correct? As it would always fail the addition property (we will end up with 2 times the constant).

Comment: The example suffices. Alternatively, note the zero vector is not in the set.

Comment: The existence of a zero vector and additive inverse is key

Comment: "Is the reasoning all correct and complete? " Yes, it is. But still it is not really an optimal solution, since noting that $0$ is not in the given set $V$ immediately gives that $V$ cannot be a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

When checking whether some set is a vector space or not, the first thing that I usually check (because it's the most simple thing to check) is if the zero vector is in that set. In this particular example if we plug the point $(0,0,0)$ in the equation we just get $0=1$, so this set is not a vector space because it does not contain the zero vector (in this case, the origin).